# Combined vertical and horizontal uiscrollview for view controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

Has anyone had experience with a combined vertical and horizontal uiscrollview? I want to create an interface where depending on which direction you swipe, it takes you to a different view controller, in sort of a + shape design. I have this so far, which creates 3 view controllers that I can swipe between. Ideally, I'd like to load to the view in the middle of the + first and then be able to swipe in any direction. Thank you in advance for any advice.

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let aVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "A") as! aVC
    let bVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "B") as! bVC;
    let cVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "C") as! cVC;


    let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let width = bounds.size.width
    let height = bounds.size.height;

    scrollView!.contentSize = CGSize(width: 3*width, height: height);

    let viewControllers = [aVC, bVC, cVC]

    var idx:Int = 0;

    for viewController in viewControllers {
        addChildViewController(viewController);
        let originX:CGFloat = CGFloat(idx) * width;
        viewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: originX, y: 0, width: width, height: height);
        scrollView!.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        idx += 1;
    }
    view.addSubview((scrollView?.superview)!)
}
```

Comment: A UIScrollView works best with *views*, not *view controllers*. (The difference is a core concept of MVC.) Instead of using scroll views for changing the main view (and it's view controller), why not using at least UIGestureRecognizers instead? Also, consider the user - they know (and probably use daily) left/right swipes to *segue* between scenes. But an up or down swipe is already used for other things from the home screen. It would be quite jarring - not necessarily a good thing - to learn how to navigate your app instead of like others.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely consider using uigesturerecognizers instead. Also, good point about the interface,I think I will have tabs that the user can pull to change the vertical view, hopefully that won't interfere with the home screen functionalities.